# How to create a drop down menu from an enum?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, enums

How could I display the values of enum structure in JSP? I use the Spring MVC to implement my project.

Many thanks!

```
public enum ProjectStatusEnum {
    INITIAL(0,"Initial"),ONGOING(1,"Ongoing"),CLOSED(2,"Closed");

    private int value;
    private String key;

    ProjectStatusEnum(int value , String key){
        this.value=value;
        this.key = key;
    }
    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    } 
    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }  
    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }
    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you think calling `setValue` will do?

Comment: dont know much about jsp, but enum has method values which returns you array of all elements, so you could do `ProjectStatusEnum[] values =ProjectStatusEnum .values()` and itterate trough all elements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the enum values in an attribute of your request:

```java
// ProjectStatusEnum.values() return an array of ProjectStatusEnum
request.setAttribute("enum", ProjectStatusEnum.values());
```

And finally, within your JSP:

```xml
<ul class="dropdownmenu">
    <c:forEach items="${enum}" var="entry">
        <li>${entry.key} (${entry.value})</li> <!-- for example -->
    </c:forEach>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why not just return .values() to the jsp and then use a c:forEach tag to iterate over them...not sure that a map is necessarily needed. It can be handy that way though.

Comment: @ScottShipp Well actually, you're right, I not sure there is any benefit to use a map in this case, I'll edit. Thanks!

Comment: Many thanks! But why could we use map to deal with enum?

Comment: @Eric See the [first version](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22614109/revisions) of my answer. A map is not necessary in your case, it was just a reflex of mine that may be useful in some other cases.

Answer (score 0):

1. Define in your ModelAttribute class the variable to bind to the type of your ENUM class

   ```
    public class YourCommand implements Serializable{
       private ProjectStatusEnum yourVariable; 
       /*setter and getter of yourVariable*/
    }
   ```
2. In the controller, put an instance of YourCommand yourCommand into Model
3. On your jsp page,

   ```
   <form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="yourCommand" ...> 
       <form:select path="yourVariable" cssErrorClass="yourErrorClass">
          <option>Select Project Status</option>
          <form:options itemLabel="key" />
       </form:select>
   </form:form>
   ```